# Performance of POD files in Cocos3d

Tags: performance, cocos3d

I've encountered problem with performance of loaded POD files. I'm using the ones created for online service with WebGL, so these models are pretty well detailed. The total number of models I got is large and I really want to avoid to remake them all. So, while increasing the number of models loaded in scene fps is dropping. Are there any general advices to improve performance without changing these models? I've disabled multisampling, tried to decrease textures' sizes, number of lights and other stuff like that. Also, all models are viewed by camera, so I could not use culling. These models are also different. Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like "the more I add the slower it gets". That's to be expected. You should run some tests and check if reducing detail (number of vertices) or textures would help improve performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I knew that there was something I've missed! :) saying in general, I created cocos3d template, than used my own mechanisms to add POD files. But if you will see into Scene.m there are

```
[self createGLBuffers];
[self releaseRedundantData];
```

methods in -initializeScene. And, of course, I did not use them after adding POD files. That helped to improve performance from 7 fps to 30.

Comment: Have you managed to get 60 FPS with a descent POD file? I'cant obtain more than 37 FPS with only a few meshes.

Comment: @rraallvv yes, I have obtained 60 fps while loading at least 40 POD files with about 2000-3000 faces within each one on iPad 3. You can see the performance in my app "Planner 5D"

Comment: wow! amazing app. I'm installing it on my iPad mini. Any suggestions on how to get higher FPS, mesh simplification for distant objects, batching, etc.

Comment: @rraallvv well, the main advices which worked a bit for me are: to use -createGLBuffers, not to use CC3Billboards, to manually create CC3MeshNodes instead of a lot of CC3PlaneNodes, turn off antialiasing and use -cullBackFaces. Also, cocos3d make frustum culling, that could be a useful feature. I don't know about distant simplification, but that could be effective too. I recommend to ask that question on cocos3d forum